# Is there a problem with my node.js server

Tags: node.js, server

So I have been trying to get a server running on my laptop which my phone can access. Many people said to typed in the iP address and do `:(insert port number)` but whenever I tried to do it my phone would not respond at all. When I tried to access it from my laptop using the same method without using localhost, it did not work I do not know what I should add in this question which will let people know the answer so I will frequently edit this question to add more details which people need to help answer my question.

This is my code at index.js

```
    const http=require('http');
const fs=require('fs');

http.createServer(function(req,res){
    fs.readFile('index.html', function(err,data){
        res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type': 'text/html'})
        res.write(data)
        return res.end()
    })
}).listen(8080, "0.0.0.0")
```

And my code at index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="code.js">
        </script>
    <script src="code2.js">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="typed" val="reeeeeee" id="typed"><br>
        <input type="text" name="filenam" val="something" id="filenam"><br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This might be a firewall issue of the server hosting machine.

Comment: Can you explain and tell me how to fix it?